# PHP session_start() would this be best practice?

Tags: php, session, isset

Depending on whether or not a user is logged in I would like to show specific information on my home page. However is the following the best way to do this?

```
<?php session_start()?>

if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {
  session_destroy();
}
else {
  show info
}
```

Is this best practice?

Comment: We have no idea what `if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {` is for.

Comment: as this is the home page everyone accesses it however I don't want to be keeping a session open when a user could access the page then just close it but I would like to display specific information if a user is logged in so this checks if the session variable set when logging in if it is set it will display the information

Comment: Sure.  But that's hardly best practice.  'Best Practice' makes me think about session fixation, entropy, etc...  READ THIS: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I understand that but any page will normally do a specific check to avoid session fixation ect. How can I achieve the desired result without doing this?

Comment: @user1754727 see [session_regenerate_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php).  But make sure you understand when to use it, like when escalating privileges / re-authing.  (see link above)

Comment: you mean *destroy* the Session (logout) if the user doesn't have the 'test' variable set?

Comment: PHP is only evaluated within `<?php` and `?>`. Your code snippet above won't do what you expect because you have put the code outside of those delimiters.

Answer (score 3):

Your code won't do anything.

It will just output:

> if (!isset($_SESSION['test'])) {   session_destroy(); } else {   show
>   info }

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/9a3iOK

Comment: Will it not check to see if the session variable test is set if it is not it will destroy the session and load the rest of the page without the specific info?

Comment: @user1754727 this is because of the closing '?>' tag at the end of session_start(), you need to remove that. http://codepad.viper-7.com/lSClvh

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty meaningless if you don't specify what `$_SESSION['test']` is, how it's set or unset.

Ballpark guess, you want to do something like:

```
<?php
session_start();

//during login
...
$_SESSION['token'] = md5($username . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

//at the top of all your pages.
if( isset($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] != md5($username . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ) {
    session_destroy();
    echo "Possible session hijacking, go away.";
    exit;
}
```

So if someone attempts to attach to the session they would be rejected as their IP would *likely* differ. If you're on a share wifi AP, and not using HTTPS or a trusted VPN then someone on the same AP could snag the session cookie and still have the same public IP address because of NAT. You could add in extra info like `$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`, but that's still spoofable if they know what they're doing.

Something like this, plus SSL should keep you safe from both session cookie hijacking and session ID bruteforcing in the vast majority of cases. The tiny minority being someone on the same NAT'ed AP as you, bruteforcing session IDs on the site you happen to be logged into at the time, and getting lucky.